# Parallelizing construction of sparsearray

Tags: performance-tuning, parallelization, sparse-arrays

I'm constructing sparse arrays where blocks of each array are results of the integral defined in `integralList`

```
indexToRep[n_] := indexToRep[n] = Module[{j, m},
j = Floor[Sqrt[n - 1]];
m = n - 1 - j^2 - j;
{j, m}]

repToIndex[j_,m_] := repToIndex[j,m] = j^2 + m + j + 1;

symmetrizeLowerDiag[mat_]:=Transpose[LowerTriangularize[mat,-1]] + mat

sphNormCoeffs[l_,m_]:=Sqrt[(2*l+1)*(l-m)!/(4*Pi*(l+m)!)]

integralList[r1_?ListQ, r2_?ListQ, limits_] := integralList[r1, r2, limits] = Block[
{$MaxExtraPrecision=500, j1 = First[r1], m1 = Last[r1],
 j2 = First[r2], m2 = Last[r2], integral, res},
integral = 2*Pi*sphNormCoeffs[j2,m2]*sphNormCoeffs[j1,m1]*Integrate[LegendreP[j1,m1,x]LegendreP[j2,m2,x],x];
res = Subtract @@ (integral /. x -> {1, limits});
N[res, $MachinePrecision]
]
```

However, the main function below is really slow for larger n.

```
projList[n_, a_]:=Block[
{ind = indexToRep /@ Range[n^2], limits = Table[1 - k/(a - 1/2),{k, 0, a - 1}], indSorted, indexofjm0,
indSortedUntiljmAre0, arraysAllAngles, symmetrized},
    indSorted=Sort[ind,#1[[2]]<#2[[2]]&];
    indexofjm0 = Total[Range[1,n]];
    indSortedUntiljmAre0 = indSorted[[1;;indexofjm0]];
    arraysAllAngles = Table[
    SparseArray[{{i_,j_} :>Evaluate[integralList[indSortedUntiljmAre0[[i]],indSortedUntiljmAre0[[j]],limits]][[k]]
            /;i>=j && Last[indSortedUntiljmAre0[[i]]] == Last[indSortedUntiljmAre0[[j]]]}, {Length[indSortedUntiljmAre0],Length[indSortedUntiljmAre0]}],{k,1,Length[limits]}];
            symmetrized = symmetrizeLowerDiag /@ arraysAllAngles;
            Return[Normal /@ symmetrized]]
```

The main computation takes place in `arraysAllAngles`. Two things I try to parallelize is:

1. `Table` (`ParallelTable` and `Parallelize @ Table` are somehow slower) which comes from evaluating `integralList` that computes a definite integral for two pairs of indices `r1` and `r2`  at different `limits`
2. `SparseArray`: `integralList` can be computed for indices `i` and `j` independently so can be parallelized

I tried to parallelize sparsearray using

```
   arraysAllAngles = Table[SparseArray[Flatten[ParallelTable[
        {{i, j} -> projInfinitySparseListMP[indSortedUntiljmAre0[[i]], indSortedUntiljmAre0[[j]], angles][[k]]}, {i, 1, imax}, {j, 1, i}]], {imax, imax}], {k, 1, Length[angles]}];
```

but it wasn't really faster. Sorry that this post got so long and would appreciate any help here!

An example of the output of `projList` is

```
In[10]:= projList[3, 2]

Out[10]= {{{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0}}, {{0.2098765432098765, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0.4567901234567901, 
   0.3312693299999688, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0.3312693299999688, 
   0.2592592592592593, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0.3333333333333333, 
   0.2868876552746235, 0.1656346649999844}, {0, 0, 0, 
   0.2868876552746235, 0.4814814814814815, 0.3849001794597505}, {0, 0,
    0, 0.1656346649999844, 0.3849001794597505, 0.3333333333333333}}}
```

In general

```
Dimensions[projList[n,a]]={a,Total[Range[1,n]],Total[Range[1,n]]}
```

Comment: What is `cosangles`? It seems to be undefined. Also a typical example call to `projList` is required. Nobody wants to make guesses here. And indeed, a _minimal_ example would be welcome. I don't think that the file input-output stuff is necessary here.

Comment: Thanks. a lot, I updated this now.

Comment: `$MaxExtraPrecision = 500`? Why?

Comment: Suggestion: Try to compute the definite integrals symbolically. Just once.